# Regex to clean database dump

Tags: php, regex

After a couple of hours I'm really desperated.
I have a database dump with tons of inlinestyles and deprecated html-tags.

What would be the regex to get this espression?

```
style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0pt;mso-layout-grid-align: none" class="MsoNormal">
```

That means I would like to get.
1. start with the word style
2. grab everything in the middle
3. stop with the closing bracket

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:** `preg_replace('/style="[^>]+>/',"",$string)`

Comment: Works perfect and saves me a lot of time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: this is not better way. because, some content is missing... i think your problem is quotation problem..  before insert into db you can use `mysql_real_escape_string` this function for content to clean. or u can googling by `quotation problem in database..`

Comment: @Ronny Linsener  check update. right way to use is `preg_replace('/style="[^>]+>/',"",$string)` and `preg_replace('style="[^>]+>',"",$string)`  is not right way..

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
preg_match('#style=".+?"\s*>#');
```

Comment: You mean preg_replace('style=".+?"\s*>') ?